How to migrate a job in the flink cluster to another task manager
I have a flink cluster of four task manager (tm). Other services are running on a task manager. Due to resource issues such as bandwidth, memory or CPU, the tm will occasionally be disconnected from the cluster.
I want to migrate some of these jobs from this tm to other tm to alleviate the problem. But I didn't find a feasible way. Is there any such solution? Looking forward to your reply.

If you're talking about specifically having some sub-tasks of some jobs not run on that problematic TM, then no, there's not a good way to do that.
If you have multiple slots per TM, or multiple TMs per server, then you could just reduce the number of slots/TMs on the over-loaded server by configuring things differently for that one server.
